# Remove Spaces and Special Characters (between Numbers only) in a string

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I am novice in RegEx. I am trying to strip all whitespaces and special characters between numbers in a string. Please know that string may contain other characters with numbers.
For Example take this string,

```
String s1 = "This is Sample AmericanExp Card Number 3400 1000 2000 009";
```

What I am trying is :-

```
String s1 = "This is Sample AmericanExp Card Number 3400 1000 2000 009";
String regExp = "[^\\w]+";
String replacement = "";
String changed= s1.replaceAll(regExp, replacement);
System..out.println("changed->"+content);
```

Its giving output as *ThisisSampleAmericanExpCardNumber340000000000009*,
The Required output is  "This is Sample AmericanExp Card Number 340010002000009".
Appreciate The Help and Please let me know the concept behind it.

EDIT:-
Now I am masking the card Number and Its Pin (PCI), So I have this formula

```
^((4\\d{3})|(5[1-5]\\d{2})|(6011))-?\\d{4}-?\\d{4}-?\\d{4}|3[4,7]\\d{13}$
```

Which Checks for some type of credit cards. I am modifying it to check for its PIN and CVV also.(Matching 4 and 6 digit numbers also)
Sample String = "Sample AmericanExp Card Number 3400 1000 2000 009 and PIN is 1234 , CVV = 654321"

I modified the formula as :

```
^((4\\d{3})|(5[1-5]\\d{2})|(6011))-?\\d{4}-?\\d{4}-?\\d{4}|3[47]\\d{13}$|^[0-9]{4}$|^[0-9]{6}$
```

Which Doesn't gives me the correct output (Matching 4 and 6 digit numbers also).

Comment: Hey! Does it have to be RegEx?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, But Is there any other way?

Comment: Your edit does not seem related to the original question. More, the [regex you posted](https://regex101.com/r/npLCHl/1) does not match your sample string

Comment: I think your edit is a new question, please consider posting a new one, with more details, as what you wrote is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
.replaceAll("(?<=\\d)[\\W_]+(?=\\d)", "")
```

Or, if you need to deal with Unicode strings:

```
.replaceAll("(?U)(?<=[0-9])[\\W_]+(?=[0-9])", "")
```

See the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/ga3r3r/1). Details:

- `(?<=\d)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a position immediately preceded with a digit
- `[\W_]+` - one or more non-word or underscore characters
- `(?=\d)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location immediately followed with a digit.

Note that the `(?U)`, `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` embedded option, will make `\W` Unicode aware and it will no longer match Cyrillic, etc. letters.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/YlXYpr):

```
String s1 = "This is Sample AmericanExp Card Number 3400 1000 2000 009";
System.out.println("changed -> " + s1.replaceAll("(?<=\\d)[\\W_]+(?=\\d)", ""));
// => changed -> This is Sample AmericanExp Card Number 340010002000009
```

Comment: It Worked Like Charm. Say If I want to add any Or condition in between like for any specific number with [\W_]+ how should I achieve this? (Say I want to check whether String contains [53] or not)

Comment: @AnandSharma I do not get it. Just use `String#contains`: `if (s1.contains("[53]")) {...}`

Comment: Its just that within this .replaceAll("(?U)(?<=[0-9])[\\W_]+(?=[0-9])", "") , if i want to add any more "OR" conditions which i guess is done by "|" character, How would that fit into this regex string. Say I want to check for  one or more non-word or underscore characters using [\W_]+ and also check whether string contains [53] or not.

Comment: @AnandSharma No, in the general case, it won't work. Check if string contains `[53]` as I showed above, then do whatever you need. If you have a specific string format in mind, please let know, share a sample string and expected output.